# Android: Your XML document has more than one root view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm using *XML* and I'm a beginner in *XML*. I basically tried to put two `TextView`s but it shows an error. How can I resolve this?

This is a screenshot of the code and the error that is showing up:

[image]

Comment: When asking a question, it is best to provide code and information as text within the question. Images are fine as supplemental information, but should not be the primary means of conveying information.

Comment: Try to add some layout outside your views, so your both views would be inside a parent layout.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

your code

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Are you using Android studio ?

Answer (score 1):

With XML you must have a single document element. There needs to be a top level "container" for the content.

Your screenshot shows that you have two TextView elements. Effectively, two XML documents, not one.

You could choose to wrap them with a document element:

```
<doc>
  <TextView/>
  <TextView/>
</doc>
```

or save each of those `TextView` elements as their own XML file.